# Why doesn't ghci provide the expected Ambiguous type variable error in this scenario?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, ghci

I'm working through [a Haskell book](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters). It has the following example:

```
ghci> Right 3 >>= \x -> return (x + 100)
```

It expects that this blows up with this error:

```
<interactive>:1:0:  
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:  
      `Error a' arising from a use of `it' at <interactive>:1:0-33  
      `Show a' arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:1:0-33  
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

When I run it:

```
$ ghci

Prelude> Right 3 >>= \x -> return (x + 100)
```

I get:

```
Right 103
```

ie I don't get the error expected.

Now maybe the compiler or the library has changed - but I'm not sure how to verify that.

My question is: **Why doesn't ghci provide the expected Ambiguous type variable error in this scenario?**

Comment: LYAH must be pretty outdated - in the couple of years I've known/used Haskell, I've never even heard of `Error` having been used in GHCi. Anyone know the history behind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to [`-XExtendedDefaultRules`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghc-flag--XExtendedDefaultRules) being now enabled by default in GHCi. To turn it off (and get your expected error message):

```
ghci> :set -XNoExtendedDefaultRules
ghci> Right 3 >>= \x -> return (x + 100)
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show b, Show a) => Show (Either a b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 11 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

This extension adds a bunch of extra ways to default otherwise ambiguous code. In your case, you have an expression of type `Num b => Either a b`. [Regular Haskell defaulting rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) tell us the `b` should default to `Integer`. The extended rules (see the link above) additionally default `a` to `()`.